# PageViewController after go to View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I have a pageViewController with 3 viewControllers which is embedded in a view of a viewcontroller.

[image]

i am setting the view controllers programatically:

```
lazy var vcArr: [UIViewController] =  {
    return [self.vcInstance(name: "vc1"),
            self.vcInstance(name: "vc2"),
            self.vcInstance(name: "vc3"),
            ]
}()
```

i am programatically setting the number of pages to 4

```
    let pageController = UIPageControl.appearance()
        pageController.numberOfPages = 4
```

what i want to happen is that if the user tries to swipe right from the 3rd page it will segue to a signup viewController.

I'm currently trying to achieve this in the viewcontroller after function testing for it the next item is greater than or equal to the total count.

```
public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                               viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = vcArr.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }
    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

    if nextIndex >= vcArr.count {

        infoClick()

        return nil

    } else {

        guard nextIndex < vcArr.count else {
            return self.vcArr.last
        }
        guard self.vcArr.count > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }
        return self.vcArr[nextIndex]
    }
}
```

with this test the way it is sometimes it stops on page 3 and then when swiped right it will segue off with my function infoClick().  however somethings it goes right off when it hits the 3rd page as you would think because its **>** or **=** the number of pages which is 3.

when i change this to just > it doesn't display anything on the third page.

[image]
[image]

I've searched heaps for a way around this but to no avail.  does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this?

attaching entire class below:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class pageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {


    @IBOutlet var createAccountBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!


    lazy var vcArr: [UIViewController] =  {
        return [self.vcInstance(name: "vc1"),
                self.vcInstance(name: "vc2"),
                self.vcInstance(name: "vc3"),
                ]
    }()

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }


    //---------------------------------------------- autoLogin


    /// temporary location, needs to be launched during the loading screen
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

//        if (PFUser.current() != nil) {
//            let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PackViewController")
//            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


//        if (PFUser.current() != nil) {
//            let tbc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTabController") as! UITabBarController
//                tbc.selectedIndex = 1
//            self.present(tbc, animated: true, completion: nil)
//        }
    }


    //---------------------------------------------- set the viewcontrollwe instance

    private func vcInstance(name: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)

    }


    //---------------------------------------------- set the direction and first page of the page controller

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

        let pageController = UIPageControl.appearance()
            pageController.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
            pageController.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = GeneralFunctions.UIColorFromHEX(hexValue: 0xbb0d2a)
            pageController.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            pageController.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
            pageController.numberOfPages = 4

        //GeneralFunctions.commonButtonSettings(buttonName: signUpButton, hexValue: 0x0c1537)

        self.dataSource = self
        self.dataSource = self
        if let firstVC = vcArr.first {
            setViewControllers([firstVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


    //---------------------------------------------- page view controller before settings

    public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                                   viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = vcArr.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }
        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

        if previousIndex < 0 {
            return nil
        } else {

            guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
                return self.vcArr.last
            }
            guard self.vcArr.count > previousIndex else {
                return nil

            }
            return self.vcArr[previousIndex]
        }
    }



    //---------------------------------------------- page view controller after settings

    public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                                   viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = vcArr.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }
        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

        if nextIndex >= vcArr.count {

            infoClick()

            return nil

        } else {

            guard nextIndex < vcArr.count else {
                return self.vcArr.last
            }
            guard self.vcArr.count > nextIndex else {
                return nil
            }
            return self.vcArr[nextIndex]
        }
    }



    //---------------------------------------------- presentation count

    public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return self.vcArr.count

    }


    //---------------------------------------------- presentation index

    public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
              let firstViewControllerIndex = vcArr.index(of: firstViewController) else {
                return 0
        }

        return firstViewControllerIndex
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }



    //---------------------------------------------- launch the new view controller - still launching before swipped to 4th window sometimes

    // not sure if this is the best way to do this need to look at this a bit more

    func infoClick()  {

        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: SignupViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignupViewController") as! SignupViewController
        let currentController = getCurrentViewController()
            currentController?.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }

    func getCurrentViewController() -> UIViewController? {

        if let rootController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            var currentController: UIViewController! = rootController
            while( currentController.presentedViewController != nil ) {
                    currentController = currentController.presentedViewController
            }
            return currentController
        }
        return nil

    }



}
```